# Unable to import mp4 video file

Tags: import, video

I'm running Mathematica 14.0 on a 2021 MacBook Pro (Apple M1 Max chip with 64 GB memory). I'm attempting to import an mp4 video file using the Import command. The code runs and produces a video window in my notebook (as expected). However when I click on the window to run the video, a red X is displayed in the window and it becomes unresponsive. The video loads and plays fine in QuickTime Player. What do I need to do to load and run the video in Mathematica?

Comment: Find "VideoFrameMap-2024-01-12T10-44-22.mp4" from the MMA installation and try to import it. If this works.